# Mysql Order by Error CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im working on sorting some data after its pulled from the database but it seems that there is some type of error when my query is executed. I'm using codeignither for my php framework.

**Here is the error**

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 'ban_created_at' ASC' at line 1

ORDER BY 'ban_created_at' ASC

Filename: ../application/models/Infractions_model.php

Line Number: 33

**And the corresponding script (Infractions_Model)**

```
    function fetch_infractions($filter = null, $direction = null){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'user_infractions', 'user' 
                    WHERE 'user_infractions'.'user_id' = 'user'.'user_id'
                    AND 'user_infractions'.'ba_is_active' != '0'";
        if ($filter != null) {
            if ($filter == 'age') {
                $filter ='ban_created_at';
                switch ($direction) {
                    case 'ASC':
                        $dir = 'ASC';
                        break;
                    case 'DESC':
                        $dir = 'DESC';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $dir = 'ASC';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dir = 'ASC';
        }
$query = "ORDER BY 'ban_created_at' " . $dir;
/*Line 33*/ $result = $this->db->query($query, array($dir));

if ($result) {
    return $result;
}else{
    return false; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code :

```
$query = "ORDER BY 'ban_created_at' " . $dir;
/*Line 33*/ $result = $this->db->query($query, array($dir));
```

Try bellow correction code :

```
$query .= " ORDER BY ban_created_at " . $dir;
/*Line 33*/ $result = $this->db->query($query);
```

First time you initialize `$query` variable `$query = "";`
but 2nd time same initialize `$query` variable `$query = "";`

so, correct is

```
$query = "query like this";
$query .= "order by like this";
```

Comment: Now I get this error 

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_infractions', 'user' WHERE 'user_infractions'.'user_id' = 'user'.'u' at line 1

SELECT * FROM 'user_infractions', 'user' WHERE 'user_infractions'.'user_id' = 'user'.'user_id' AND 'user_infractions'.'ba_is_active' != '0' ORDER BY ban_created_at ASC

Filename: ../application/models/Infractions_model.php

Line Number: 33

Comment: please avoid single quotation in your sql query (table name and field name).
like `select *form 'user'` is not correct. correct is `seelct *from user`

Answer (score 0):

In your ERROR

```
'ORDER BY 'ban_created_at' ASC'
          ^              ^
```

---

Do like this

```
$query = "ORDER BY ban_created_at "."$dir";
```

And your `switch` condition  comes out of `IF` condition will suites best

Comment: The error remains the same but with but with the changes above reflected;
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY ban_created_at ASC' at line 1

ORDER BY ban_created_at ASC

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I wonder if you have a spelling error on this field name `ba_is_active` and it should be `ban_is_active`